# Will multiple dispatcherservlet will share controller and other components in spring MVC?

Tags: spring

Will multiple dispatcherservlet will share controller and other components in spring MVC

Answer (score 0):

They are working by servlet specification which means that they won't share. It will just for different URI mappings dispatch by different servlets as it suppose to be for servlet. Those controllers should present in web application context provided for `dispatcherServlet` instance. You can reuse controllers from different contexts.

Dispatcher servlet should be just one as it implements front controller pattern. I don't understand why you need multiple instances in the first place.